# Prevent typing non-numeric in input field on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have JS which prevents typing non-numeric character in desktop browser:

```js
<script> 
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="score" maxlength="2" 
size="2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">
```

The problem is that on my android`s browser (chrome 60.0.3112.116) this restriction doest work. I can freely type letters in input field. How to improve the code so to have the same restriction on mobile device as on desktop browser.

Comment: Instead of `type="text"`  try `type="number"`

Comment: That changes the look of input field. My goal is to keep same input filed as text field.

Comment: facing the same problem.. anyone solved this?